# Is there a markup for multiple spaces in code?

Tags: support, markdown, whitespace

I would like to put a string of spaces in code in an SO answer:

ddl1.Items.Add("12         34")

Without code, I can use `&nbsp;`. In code, I cannot:

`ddl1.Items.Add("12 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 34")`

And, in code, these six spaces collapse into one:

`ddl1.Items.Add("12      34")`

Is there a way to show a string of spaces in code mode?

Comment: *In code, these six spaces collapse into one.* In my experience, they don't. Are you positive you're using code blocks (four leading spaces) and not another type of formatting?

Comment: That's the solution! It collapses when you use `backward quotes` for the code, but not in an indented code block. Is that intentional?

Comment: I believe so. Backticks are used for inline code spans (function or variable names in a sentence, for instance), preserving whitespace is not their primary goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using four space markdown like this:

```
ddl1.Items.Add("12      34")
```